# setting a date format in a dropdownlist from 2012/11/01 to November 2012 format C#

Tags: c#

Hi guys i need help with C#, How do i format a dataTextField with a date using DataTextFormatingString.

```
    monstart.DataSource = dt;

   monstart.DataTextField = "Period";//This return 2012/11/01, and i want to display it as November 2012
   monstart.DataValueField = "SalaryMonthYear"; 
   //monstart.DataTextFormatString = "";
   monstart.DataBind();
   monstart.Items.Insert(0, " ");
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just set the format:

```
monstart.DataTextFormatString = "{0:MMMM yyyy}";
```

To address our question on whether or not custom formats are in fact allowed. The code calls `DataBinder.GetPropertyValue`, and it uses the general `string.Format` to do the formatting:

```
// .NET DataBinder class
public static string GetPropertyValue(object container, string propName,
    string format)
{
    object propertyValue = DataBinder.GetPropertyValue(container, propName);
    if (propertyValue == null || propertyValue == DBNull.Value)
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(format))
    {
        return propertyValue.ToString();
    }
    return string.Format(format, propertyValue);
}
```

thus indicating that custom formats will operate in this scope.

Comment: Are really all format strings supported or only those listed [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.datatextformatstring(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: @TimSchmelter, I'd have to check the source code because the documentation is a bit vague. Not surprising. It does state `Use the DataTextFormatString property to provide a **custom display format** the items in a list control.` However, from personal experience I believe I remember doing something very similar to this. Let me pull up the source code.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, please see my edit and let me know if I've missed something.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, I think there are some gotcha's with `string.Format`. If I'm not mistaken, if the `Type` isn't correct, it still doesn't work. So, for example, if the `Type` were actually a `string`, the formatting wouldn't work here. I know I've had issues with that before in the past.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud, i try to use the above format: "{0:MMMM yyyy}" but unfortunately it doesn't work and did not give me an error, it still display the dates as 2011/11/01 on a dropdownlist.

Comment: @user2582729: the underlying data type, is it `DateTime`?

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud No its not a DateTime its a string.

Comment: @user2582729, you're going to need to change the underlying data type of that field if you want this to work at all here because it needs to be a `DateTime`.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud, I change the data type to **DateTime** and it solved all the problems....

Comment: @user2582729, I'm glad I could be of assistance!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this format:

```
   monstart.DataTextFormatString = "MMMM dd. yyyy"
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this actually won't work. Per the documentation it requires the syntax shown in my answer. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.datatextformatstring(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud ohh, I just tested it on a "normal" datetime.. also OP didn't whan the actual date - so to be fair i'm a bit off :) (+1 to you)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
monstart.DataTextFormatString = "{MMMM yyyy}";
```

Comment: When i use this formatting(monstart.DataTextFormatString = "{MMMM yyyy}";) i get an error "Input string was not in a correct format."